# Batch Script - Wait 5 seconds before exec program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sleep

I have the below script but it does not sleep before executing the software.

Any ideas?

```
@echo off
SLEEP 10
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\..."
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are (at least) the following options, as others already stated:

1. To use the [`timeout` command](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html):

   ```cmd
   rem // Allow a key-press to abort the wait; `/T` can be omitted:
   timeout /T 5
   timeout 5
   rem // Do not allow a key-press to abort the wait:
   timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK
   rem // Suppress the message `Waiting for ? seconds, press a key to continue ...`:
   timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK > nul
   ```

   Caveats:

   - `timeout` actually counts second multiples, therefore the wait time is actually something from 4 to 5 seconds. This is particularly annoying and disturbing for short wait times.
   - You cannot use `timeout` in a block of code whose input is [redirected](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), because it aborts immediately, throwing the error message `ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.`. Hence `timeout /T 5 < nul` fails.
2. To use the [`ping` command](http://ss64.com/nt/ping.html):

   ```cmd
   rem /* The IP address 127.0.0.1 (home) always exists;
   rem    the standard ping interval is 1 second; so you need to do
   rem    one more ping attempt than you want intervals to elapse: */
   ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
   ```

   This is the only reliable way to guarantee the minimum wait time. Redirection is no problem.

Comment: in powershell nul does not work - use $null instead. eg.
 ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6  > $null

Answer (score 1):

Try the `timeout` command.

timeout /t 10

This shows `Waiting for 10 seconds, press a key to continue ...`

You can use the `/nobreak` switch that ignores user input (other than CTRL-C)

```
timeout /t 30 /nobreak
```

Or you can redirect its output to NUL for a blank screen that waits 10 seconds and ignores user input:

```
timeout /t 30 /nobreak > NUL
```